Android SDK version mismatch in React Native project
I'm developing a React Native project, and my build.gradle is configured as follows:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}


However, when I run npx react-native doctor, I receive the following error:
Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
  - Versions found: 30.0.3, 35.0.0
  - Version supported: 33.0.0


I've already confirmed that Android SDK version 33 is installed. The SDK Manager shows android-33 under SDK Platforms. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Ensured the correct SDK versions are installed.
Verified ANDROID_HOME environment variable points to the correct SDK path.
Checked build.gradle settings match version 33.

How can I resolve this mismatch and ensure that React Native recognizes SDK 33 properly?
Is there a way to force React Native or Android Studio to prioritize SDK 33 over the others installed?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

its asking for the build tools version not the sdk version

The error message is a bit misleading as there is the Android SDK Platform and the Android SDK Build-tools. The mentioned versions would fit to both. Therefore check Android SDK manager for installed Build tools version.
